# Embed iphone simulator in a website

Tags: php, html, iphone, smartphone

I would like to embed an iphone/smartphone simulator in my website. I found this one:

https://github.com/rioleo/web-iphone-simulator

After adding the files to my directories, and trying to embed it:

```
<div align="center"><iframe src="http://localhost:8080/iphone?url=mysite" width="540" height="900" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

A blank frame shows up with the message "The server refused the connection".

What causes the problem, and does anyone know other free simulators that can be embedded in websites?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dynamically modifying the navigator.userAgent string using JS? Take a look [here](http://hynchrstn.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/make-custom-javascript-navigator-useragent/).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with iphone.php?url=mysite instead iphone?url=mysite??